# Converting current sources to voltage sources

Tags: output

Are the circuits in the figure equivalent?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just want to ask if I can do the convertion that I did

Comment: Have you tried to simulate it?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way would be to combine the paralell resistance with the current source .

I have tried show it below check it out . [image]